# AWS ECS containers are not connecting but works perfectly in my local machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have an application(runs at http://localhost:8080) that talks to a backend api which runs at http://localhost:8081. I have dockerized the frontend and the backend separately and running them through docker-compose locally works perfectly without any issues. But, when I run it in ECS, the frontend couldn't find http://localhost:8081(backend).

I am using an AutoScaling group with an Elastic Load Balancer and I have my both containers defined in a single Task Definition. Also, I have the backend linked to the front end. When I ssh into my ECS instance and run `docker ps -a` i can see both of my containers are running at the correct ports exactly like in my local machine([Result of docker ps -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYqRU.png)) and I can successfully ping each of them from one container to the other.

Task Definition

```
"CartTaskDefinition": {
   "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
   "Properties": {
      "ContainerDefinitions": [
       {
          "Name": "cs-cart",
          "Image": "thishandp7/cs-cart",
          "Memory": 400,
          "PortMappings":[
            {
               "ContainerPort": "8080",
               "HostPort": "8080"
            }
          ],
          "Links": [
              "cs-server"
           ]
       },
       {
          "Name": "cs-server",
          "Image": "thishandp7/cs-server",
          "Memory": 450,
          "PortMappings":[
           {
              "ContainerPort": "8081",
              "HostPort": "8081"
           }
          ],
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

Listeners in my ElasticLoadBalancer,
The first listener is for the frontend and the second one is for the backend

```
"Listeners" : [
  {
    "LoadBalancerPort": 80,
    "InstancePort": 8080,
    "Protocol": "http"
  },
  {
    "LoadBalancerPort": 8081,
    "InstancePort": 8081,
    "Protocol": "tcp"
  }
],
```

EC2 instacne security Group Ingress rules:

```
"SecurityGroupIngress" : [
 {
   "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
   "FromPort" : 8080,
   "ToPort" : 8080,
   "SourceSecurityGroupId" : { "Ref": "ElbSecurityGroup" }
 },
 {
   "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
   "FromPort" : 8081,
   "ToPort" : 8081,
   "SourceSecurityGroupId" : { "Ref": "ElbSecurityGroup" }
 },
 {
   "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
   "FromPort" : 22,
   "ToPort" : 22,
   "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
 }
],
```

Docker Compose

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  cart:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        APP_LOCATION: /redux-saga-cart/
        PORT: 8080
    networks:
      - server-cart
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - server

  server:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        APP_LOCATION: /redux-saga-shopping-cart-server/
        PORT: 8081
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - server-cart


networks:
  server-cart:
```

Quick update: I have tried it with awsvpc network mode with application load balancer. Still not working

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to telnet the port ?

Comment: @JogendraKumar Nop, I cannot telnet the port from one container to the other.

Comment: @thishandp7 have you tried calling one another container through DNS name (means through conatiner names)

Comment: @karansharma I don't know how to call a container through the DNS name or container name. Could you show me an example so I can try and let you know? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of Docker Network mode are you using(Brdige/Host) on ECS?. I don't think **localhost** will work properly on ECS containers. I had same issue so I used private IP or DNS name of EC2 host for my communication as temp testing purpose. Ex - http://10.0.1.100:8081.

Note - Please make sure to give security group rule to allow 8081 traffic from within EC2(Edit EC2 security group to allow 8081 from same sgid as source).

For Production deployments, I would recommend to use a service discovery to identify the backend service(Consul by Hashicorp) or AWS Private Service Discovery on ECS.

---

-- Update --

Since you are running both containers under same task def(under same ECS service), so typically ECS will bring both docker containers on same host. Do something like following.

1. By default ECS brings containers using Bridge mode on Linux.
2. You should be able to have each containers communicate using Docker Gateway IP - 172.17.0.1 on Linux. So for your case, try configuring http://172.17.0.1:8081

Comment: good point. but I'm using an autoscaling group. So getting the private IP or the DNS name of the particular instance is not possible in cloudformation I presume. I tried passing the DNS of the elb through an environment variable, but that didn't help as well. when i ssh into my EC2 instance i can see both of my containers running at 0.0.0.0/<Port> which is localhost inside of the EC2 instance. So technically I think it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I have tried with both network modes. I even tried awsvpc. But no use.And I have both of the containers defined in the same task definition. Do I still have to do Service Discovery?

Comment: @thishandp7 Since you are running both containers under same task def(under same ECS service), so typically ECS will bring both docker containers on same host. Do something like following.

1. By default ECS brings containers using Bridge mode on Linux.
2. You should be able to have each containers communicate using Docker Gateway IP - 172.17.0.1 on Linux.
3. So for your case, try configuraing http://172.17.0.1:8081 under front end service and let me know the result.

I tested above in my personal workspace, it worked. Please let me know if it works for you then I will update the answer.

Comment: This works! I can cURL from the frontend service container and get the correct data from the backend container but when I do a fetch call inside the frontend app, it couldn't connect to the backend. But I think your answer is sufficient for this question. I think I should open a new question for the fetch problem one. You can go ahead and update your answer. I'll mark as correct. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: This also works with `host` network. Thanks a lot that saves me from using service discovery for my single node ecs "cluster"

Comment: This didn't work for me. Also, I'm not sure this would work anyway if you had multiple tasks on the same instance.